# Dysfunctional Keyboard in Elementary OS SeaBIOS Dual Boot

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, elementary-os, chrome-os, chrome-book

I just used [Fascinating Captain's guide](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/projects/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux/) to dual boot Elementary g OS on a Dell Inspiron Chromebook using SeaBIOS.

Everything went smoothly until I was in Elementary OS and found that my keyboard didn't work at all. None of the letters or numbers worked, and neither did the F1-12 keys. The touchpad still works, but there's not much you can do without a keyboard in Linux.

Comment: Please edit to include the specific model of your hardware (like Dell Chromebook 3120 for example), as you are asking a question about specific hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS is intended to be run on Macs or Windows PCs. Chromebooks are a bit different than the former and support in distributions may be lacking or incomplete, particularly for newer models. You may have more luck using [GalliumOS](http://galliumos.org/) or following articles in the [Arch Wiki about Chromebooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices/Chromebook).

Some of the features and configuration may be easy to port to your favorite distribution of choice, others may be more difficult. A newer kernel may help detecting the keyboard, but won't work well with non-Chromebook keyboard layouts. You could take a look at the respective GalliumOS packages ([1](http://apt.galliumos.org/pool/main/l/linux-image-galliumos/), [2](http://apt.galliumos.org/pool/main/x/xkeyboard-config/)).

The guide you are referring to is from 2016 and if I recall correctly John Lewis hasn't updated his ROMs for a long time, while https://mrchromebox.tech/ is still active.